# Flot: show numbers on stacked chart

Tags: jquery, flot

I'm using Plot to display different charts, and the plugin flot-barnumbers-enhanced to display values on them.

The problem is with the stacked charts, the output is like this:

[image]

The first problem is regarding the position on the labels, and the second is that I need the value of the single portion, not the sum as it is currently happening.

My formatter is:

```
formatter: function (value) {
     return value.toFixed(2) + '%';
}
```

Comment: Can you build a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) which shows your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I built a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3scdk7ae/1/) with sample data to illustrate how to use the [barnumbers](https://github.com/jasonroman/flot-barnumbers-enhanced) and [stacked](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/stacking/) plugins together. The options below place the bar number in the middle of the stacked bar section:

```
var options = {
    series: {
        bars: {
            show: true,
            barWidth: .9,
            align: "center",
            numbers: {
                show: true,
                formatter: function (value) {
                    return value.toFixed(2) + '%';
                },
                xAlign: function(x){
                    return x;
                },
                //xOffset: 15,
                //yOffset: 20
            }
        }
        stack: true
    }
};
```

The `xAlign` function returns  the x value, which is the horizontal center of the bar. You can use `xOffset` or `yOffset` options to specify a pixel offset of the bar number labels.

I wasn't able to reproduce the fiddle using the sum of bars like you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you! My problem was that I was using raw data and stackpercentage: true . So I resolved calculating prior the percentage and then setting it up as in your example.